# Pig grouping users while maintaining other fields

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I guess this question is similar to this one:

[Selecting fields after grouping in Pig](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17370222/selecting-fields-after-grouping-in-pig?rq=1)

but here is my question for the following made up sample data:

> user_name, movie_name, company, rating
>
> Jim, Jaws, A, 4
>
> Jim, Baseball, B, 4
>
> Matt, Halo, A, 5
>
> Matt, Baseball, B, 4
>
> Matt, History of Chairs, B, 3.5
>
> Pat, History of Chairs, B, 3
>
> John, History of Chairs, B, 2
>
> Frank, Battle Tanks, A, 3
>
> Frank, History of Chairs, B, 5

How can I group together all movies a user has seen without losing the other information like company, and rating.

I want to add the cross of all ratings a user gave from movie company A and movie company B.

> Jim, Jaws, Baseball, 8
>
> Matt, Halo, Baseball, 9
>
> Frank, Battle Tanks, History of Chairs, 8

would be the output in the format:

user, companyA, companyB, rating

I started with a load followed by

```
r1 = LOAD 'data.csv' USING PigStorage(',') as (user_name:chararray, movie_name:chararray, company_name:chararray, rating:int);
r2 = group r1 by user_name;             
r3 = foreach r2 generate group as user_name, flatten(r1);
r4A = filter r3 by company_name == 'A';
r4B = filter r3 by company_name == 'B';
```

but then I have something like

> (Frank,Frank,Battle Tanks,A,3)

I then plan to do a cross of r4A and r4B and sum of the ratings. But I'm not sure if the repeated user_name will increase the inefficiencies.

Is this the proper approach? Any ideas to make this better?
Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: you want output something like that?. user,<listofmoviesA>,<listofmoviesB>,<Sum of rating A + B>?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this?

**input:**

```
Jim,Jaws,A,4
Jim,Baseball,B,4
Matt,Halo,A,5
Matt,Baseball,B,4
Matt,History of Chairs,B,3.5
Pat,History of Chairs,B,3
John,History of Chairs,B,2
Frank,Battle Tanks,A,3
Frank,History of Chairs,B,5
```

**PigScript:**

```
A = LOAD 'input' USING PigStorage(',') AS (user_name:chararray, movie_name:chararray, company:chararray, rating:float);
B = GROUP A BY user_name;
C = FOREACH B {
                filterCompanyA = FILTER A BY company=='A';
                sumA = SUM(filterCompanyA.rating);

                filterCompanyB = FILTER A BY company=='B';
                sumB = SUM(filterCompanyB.rating);

                GENERATE group AS user,
                         FLATTEN(REPLACE(BagToString(filterCompanyA.movie_name),'_',',')) AS companyA,
                         FLATTEN(REPLACE(BagToString(filterCompanyB.movie_name),'_',',')) AS companyB,
                         (((sumA is null)?0:sumA)+((sumB is null)?0:sumB)) AS Rating;
              }

D = FOREACH C GENERATE user,companyA,companyB,Rating;
DUMP D;
```

**Output:**

```
(Jim,Jaws,Baseball,8.0)
(Pat,,History of Chairs,3.0)
(John,,History of Chairs,2.0)
(Matt,Halo,Baseball,History of Chairs,12.5)
(Frank,Battle Tanks,History of Chairs,8.0)
```

In the above output `Pat and John` haven't seen any movie in the CompanyA, so that output is null ie empty

Comment: you want to store the output?

Comment: won't this produce an unnecessarily large relation?
Also I tried running it and was returned (user1,,,0.0) for both C and D. I never was familiar with that foreach { } syntax before though

Comment: yeah, Its nested FOREACH and its efficient in terms of performance. Have you tried with same input or different set of input? Can you tell me for what input its not working?

Comment: oh my fault, I got that to output but I framed my question poorly. Because I need to sum up movie combinations between users, but only if they also saw it. I think the null for some would interfere. Basically if both Jim and Jeremy saw Jaws and Baseball, I need to find the sum of those, and then sum between different users: <company A> <company B> <sum users_who_saw that combo>

Comment: I still don't understand what exactly you need. update the question area with all those details. you mentioned Jermey as an user but i couldn't find in the input. Can you clearly mention your inputs and what exactly you want as an output.